# get table name from union table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have union table in mysql, but I need to get name table to show my data.
here mysql code

```
$blog = mysql_query("SELECT gambar FROM life
UNION ALL
SELECT gambar FROM places 
UNION ALL
SELECT gambar FROM style
UNION ALL
SELECT gambar FROM art
order by RAND() ");
```

then in php they show but I have problem for the image, as the image in different folder based on table name
here my php code

```
 $tes = mysql_query("SELECT gambar FROM life
UNION ALL
SELECT gambar FROM places 
UNION ALL
SELECT gambar FROM style
UNION ALL
SELECT gambar FROM art
order by RAND() ");
while($b=mysql_fetch_array($tes)){
echo "<img src='img/table_name/$b[pic]'>";
}
```

"table_name" it should be the table name of data on union table

Comment: While this isn't an answer, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: I'm still using mysql_ and I need the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add it to the subqueries:

```
SELECT judul, 'life' as table_name FROM life
UNION ALL
SELECT judul, 'places' FROM places 
UNION ALL
SELECT judul, 'style' FROM style
UNION ALL
SELECT judul, 'art' FROM art
order by RAND()
```

Comment: and then what shoud i wrote table_name  in <img src='img/table_name/$b[pic]'>?